# Azure Media Service V3 metadata

Tags: c#, azure, azure-media-services

I am rewriting our Azure Media Service integration from V2 to V3 but I cannot from the documentation work out how to access the metadata on an encoded video to get the duration of the video.

I have managed to upload, encode and publish a locator and get the DASH url but the access to metadata appears to be missing on the Asset object.

Is this available yet in version 3 of the API?  The V3 documentation mentions the Output metadata but not how to access it:

> https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/media-services/latest/output-metadata-schema

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the output Asset, you should find a file named {GUID}_metadata.json

We will follow up and update our documentation.

Comment: Many thanks, this put me in the right direction.  Once the asset is encoded there will be a new container in the blob storage with that asset name and within that container are all the encoded assets as well as the metadata.json.  I was able to download this once the encoding job was finished and extract the data I needed.